# Access: DELETE query with WHERE <> clause: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to run this DELETE query:

```
DELETE * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID <> (SELECT Table1.ID FROM Table1 WHERE ....)
```

The query in brackets returns all the IDs I want to keep in Table1 (This query works on it's own, I tested it). But as soon as I add the DELETE part I get the following error: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery". I tried the Code

```
DELETE * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table1.ID FROM Table1 WHERE ....)
```

But now my database hangs and doesn't do anything anymore...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's probably not "hanging", but just taking a lot of time. How many rows do you want to delete?

Comment: How long does the subquery takes when run by itself?

Comment: The subquery takes 3 seconds. I want to delete 140.000 rows with 39 columns.

Comment: Yep, deleting 140k rows is going to take time. Specially for a tiny database engine such as Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `*` is not necessary for delete statements because it deletes the entire row that matches the where condition. 
Generally `<>` (Not equal to) is used to provide a single static value. (like below)

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID <> 1
```

But the subquery returns rows/records (with the selected columns). Hence you got the error: `At most one record can be returned by this subquery`

Coming to the `NOT IN` clause that you are using, it is the right way to do it, but `NOT IN` can become pretty complex if more number of rows are involved in the subquery as `NOT IN` does a join behind the hood.

The best way in your case is to use `NOT(condition)` as you already know the `condition` for which you need the required table IDs. (like below)

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE NOT(condition)
```

This does your job pretty fast as there are no joins involved like in the earlier case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortnunately the WHERE NOT() doesn't work in Access. Do you know another possibility to do that?

Comment: But I do see that `not` is available [here](https://superuser.com/a/1063740/914189)